# Why does SharePoint 2013 JSON User Profile properties require full control?

Tags: json, sharepoint-2013

Why does it require Full Control permission to retrieve read-only user profile properties when using JSOM in a provider-hosted app when this isn't possible to grant that level of permission in a SharePoint Online (O365) site. I receive a access denied message when trying to get user profile properties like PictureUrl for another user unless the app has Full Control Tenant permission.

In the docs, it mentions that you can grant Read access for sharepoint/social/tenant, however this method requires Full Control ?